# How to set a windows service's log on user and password interactivley via PowerShell?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, service

I'm looking to drop a line of code into an install script that will prompt for the user name and password to be set to run an existing windows service.  Yes, it is simple enough to open services.msc for this, but I was hoping to have it open up in the foreground while the install script is running.

I've seen this sort of thing when installing a ***new service*** via installutil.exe for .Net - a little dialog box pops up asking for the credentials to run the service with, but I'm stumped on this one...

I've tried adding the PS below, but it must have predefined user credentials and isn't exactly what I need...

```
$LocalSrv = Get-WmiObject Win32_service -filter "name='SERVICE'"
$LocalSrv.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$false,".\User","Password")
```

FYI, I am not looking for a solution in which the user account info is set within the script.  The end users can barely run the thing, let alone modify it so **it must be interactive** in PowerShell or a dialog box.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wrote about how to do this a while back. See [IT Pro Today - Changing Service Credentials Using PowerShell](http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/changing-service-credentials-using-powershell).

Comment: BINGO!  Thanks for your input, Bill.  I'll leave the code here so it's easier for the next guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Bill, I was able to figure this out.  Below is the code I am using to the have end users update the service's login account interactively during an installation script.  I hope this helps somebody else in the future - I know it is making my life easier!   Just update the name of "$YourService" with the service you are targeting.

```
$YourService = "YourServiceName"
$credential = Get-Credential

$params = @{
  "Namespace" = "root\CIMV2"
  "Class" = "Win32_Service"
  "Filter" = "Name='$YourService'"
}
$service = Get-WmiObject @params

$service.Change($null,
  $null,
  $null,
  $null,
  $null,
  $null,
  $credential.UserName,
  $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password,
  $null,
  $null,
  $null)

Restart-Service $YourService

Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter  "Name='$YourService'" | 

Select-Object Name,StartName | Write-Host -fore Green

Write-Host -fore Yellow ***Verify Correct Login Account Above ***

PAUSE
```